# How can I postpone context.savechanges of multiple context that operate in different methods of a webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, dbcontext

What I'd like to do is to work on separate contexts (declare in separate methods) and postpone the `SaveChanges()` of each one of them in a dedicated method since the interact on the related entites of the DB

The issue here is that I am working on a webform : this is POSTBACK land. As a result, declaring a single context for the page will trigger a multiple context error since after each postback a new context will be created. If I `dispose` the context to avoid postback issue, I lose all the data in the current transaction (not what I want)

What if I used a `utilities` class? This could allow to create a static context. I was told this is not a good Idea.

I have tried serialization. My `xmlserializer` doesn't want to serialise my DbSet objects nor my entity class types. I don't want to keep data in a list to avoid memory issues since there is A LOT OF DATA being processed.

Below the structure of the code behing of my webform

How

```
protected void MyMethod1()
{
    using(var = context1 = new MyDbContext())
    {// Do some work BUT no context1.SaveChanges()}
}

protected void MyMethod2()
{
    MyMethod1();
    using(var = context2 = new MyDbContext())
    {// Do some work BUT no context2.SaveChanges()}
}

protected class MeMethod3()
{
     context1.SaveChanges();
     context2.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to save in the 3rd method instead of where the context is declared? Why do you want multiple contexts?

Comment: @mason Hey I guess this time my snippet is MVCE compliant.... I need things that way because each method here is an event (add, modify, delete..) of CRUD. So in the same session, if I persist my CRUD operation, not only it's not wise for performance but it can lead other error i.e. I can do a `rollback` with EF `SaveChanges`... so that's  my issue here

Comment: An MCVE is required if you're talking about a problem with existing code. If you're asking how to structure code, that's different.

Comment: @mason Roger that. I've just presented my application (remember yesterday we talked a lot about an XML issue)... Teacher was ok about my work. FOr the XML issue, it has fixed itself I don't know how...For the issue of the current question, I changed the approach and used serialized objects

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for involves 2 changes:

1. Declare an independent class for your Context Manger.

   ```
   public class DbContextManager<C> : IDisposable where C : DbContext
   ```

Inside this class, declare a public static method that returns an open Context:

```
    public static DbContextManager<C> GetManager()
```

Each time you need to open a context connection you just call it like this:

```
    using (var ctx = ContextManager<YourContext>.GetManager())
```

You should have [YourContext] defined as:

```
    public partial class YourContext : DbContext
```

Each time the ContextManager.GetManager() gets called, it should check if an internal associated context (a private property of type C: `private C _context;`) is open. If not, it just creates a new context and saves its reference internally (to that private static property of type C). Or you can also save it as a reference in some Global Properties Context your system uses for storing widespread system variables.

It also adds 1 to an internal integer counter, indicating how many references is this ContextManager handling.

All your CRUD ops should be executed inside the declared `using (var ctx = ContextManager<YourContext>.GetManager())`

When your code exits the `using` block, the `ContextManager` executes it's `Dispose()` method (as the class should implement `IDisposable`). Inside the \ `Dispose()` method, you shoud DeRef your internal integer counter. When your internal counter reaches 0 you should free the DbContext you had opened, as no extra context ops are needed.

This will give you the benefit of sharing / keeping only 1 open connection to the database, for each session that is using your system.

Remember to use `lock (_lock)` (object _lock) before updating static properties / fields in a multi thread environment.

2. Use Native .Net Transactions: In order to postpone the actual `SaveChanges()` executions, before opening your contexts, use a `TransactionScope(..)` block:

   ```
   using (TransactionScope tr = new TransactionScope())
   ```

Upon exiting the `using(TransactionScope...)` all the `SaveChanges()` will actually be persisted to the database. If something goes wrong while executing your CRUD ops, `TransactionScope` will take care of rolling back everything for you.

If you nest `using (TransactionScope tr = new TransactionScope())`, or you open more than one DbContext connection, the .Net Transaction Manager will automatically upgrade to `Enterprise Services` and will automatically use `Windows Distributed Transaction Coordinator Service` on all Windows Servers pointed by your open DbContext connections. In this case, you should also configure all your DTCs on all participating Sql servers so that the can [see and talk] to each other in order to accomplish this complex scenario.

---

If you need a working `DbContextManager` class, let me know and I'll attach one as an example.